# Bitbucket Visual Studio plug-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, bitbucket

I am trying to find a plug in for Visual Studio 2010-2012 to operate with Bitbucket, but i can't find a clear solution. I would like to find something like Ankh in Tortoise.

I would appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found a solution than fits to me.

I tried [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9bc074fa-9e1f-4ce2-a75d-b90e65f7475a) and is working properly.